# Cannot coerce HashSet<&str> into HashSet<&String>

Tags: string, types, rust

While messing around with some example code, I found I could not coerce `HastSet<&String>` into `HashSet<&str>` or vice versa.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    // move strings into HashSet
    let known_values: HashSet<&str> = ["a", "b", "c"]
        .iter().cloned().collect();

    // provided an Vec<String>
    let provided_values: Vec<String> = vec![
        "a".to_string(),
        "b".to_string(),
        "z".to_string()
    ];

    // hash set of refrences
    let mut found: HashSet<&String> = HashSet::new();
    found.insert(&provided_values[0]);
    found.insert(&provided_values[1]);
    found.insert(&provided_values[2]);

    //let missing = known_values.difference(&found);
    let missing = found.difference(&known_values);

    println!("missing: {:#?}", missing);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f681ef9a1765b498dd22e2c0c5fb5d1))

Compiler Error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:36
   |
23 |     let missing = found.difference(&known_values);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found `str`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&std::collections::HashSet<&std::string::String>`
              found reference `&std::collections::HashSet<&str>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

I know you can coerce `&String` into `&str` and vice versa, so I am a little surprised it did not extend to `HashSet<&String>` and `HashSet<&str>`. What ways are there to get around this without just allocating `String`s?

Comment: "I know you can coerce &String into &str and vice versa" no you can't turn a &str to a &String

Comment: I don't understand your question both don't compile

Comment: @Stargateur What I mean is that if you have a variable of some of &String it can be passed around as &str, like in function calls.

Comment: yes, my point is it's not vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to have a different type of `HashSet`. Change `found` to a `HashSet<&str>` and the program works.

```
// hash set of references
let mut found: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();
found.insert(&provided_values[0]);
found.insert(&provided_values[1]);
found.insert(&provided_values[2]);
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8fe779fd1a000d240ba13a9e34a73af1))